# How can I code my view controller to perform a push segue to another view?

Tags: xcode, push, segue

How can I code my view controller to perform a push segue to another view? I know how to do it with the storyboard, but, I can't figure out how to do it with some coding.

Comment: Please check this previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637945/how-do-i-set-a-modal-segue-programmatically-to-a-push-segue

Answer (score 0):

If your view controllers are connected with a segue and if you just want to perform that segue just do:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
```

---

If they're not connected you can set the **Storyboard ID** of your view controller in the **Identity Inspector** (⌥⌘3) and use this code to initiate the push segue:

```
UIViewController *aViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your Storyboard ID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

---

Also, these methods are really useful to manipulate segues:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```