# Force one method to wait for another to complete

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my original view controller before I segue to the Destination View Controller, I call a method that gets my key parameter and I then set the key parameter in my destination view controller in the following method. However, the key parameter is set before the `doSomethingToGetKey` method is completed so a null value is passed. I was wondering if there was a way to make the second method wait for the first one to finish.

Origin View Controller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

[self doSomethingToGetKey];
[segue.destinationViewController setKey:_key];
}

-(void)doSomethingToGetKey:(ACAccount *)account{

[_apiObject postReverseOAuthTokenRequest:^(NSString *authenticationHeader) {

    APIObject *api = [APIObject APIOSWithAccount:account];
    [api verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {


        [api postReverseAuthAccessTokenWithAuthenticationHeader:authenticationHeader successBlock:^(NSString *oAuthToken, NSString *oAuthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {

            _key = oAuthToken;
            _secret = oAuthTokenSecret;
            _userId = userID;



        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"ERROR 1, %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            exit(1);

        }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"ERROR 2: %@",error.description);
        exit(1);

    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"ERROR 3: %@",error.description);
    exit(1);

}];

};
```

Comment: Is your doSomethingToGetKey asynchronous?

Comment: Yes it is asynchronous

Comment: You need to change `doSomethingToGetKey` to accept a completion block that is invoked when it finishes. Then call `[segue.destinationViewController setKey:_key]` inside that completion block.

Comment: Can you post code of this method?

Comment: Yup, just posted the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the pattern involves employing a completion block, e.g.:

```
- (void) doSomethingToGetKeyWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *key))completion
{
    // perform asynchronous request

    // in its completion handler, call the `completion` block parameter given above

    [api doingSomeOtherAsynchronousMethodWithCompletion:^{
        completion(key);
    }];
}
```

Then, instead of:

```
[self doSomethingToGetKey];
[self doSomethingElseWithKey:_key];
```

You could do:

```
[self doSomethingToGetKeyWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *key){
    [self doSomethingElseWithKey:key];
}];
```

---

But, in this case, you're trying to do all of this inside `prepareForSegue`. That changes the problem entirely, because the segue will still be performed before this asynchronous method is called, defeating the purpose of this completion block pattern.

You therefore also want to change your button (or whatever) to not perform the segue itself, but rather call an `IBAction`, and then have *that* perform the segue programmatically ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16182263/1271826)). Thus, you'd end up with an `IBAction` like:

```
- (IBAction)tappedButton:(id)sender 
{
    // perhaps update UI so user knows something slow is happening first, 
    // e.g., show a `UIActivityIndicatorView`

    [self doSomethingToGetKeyWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *key){

        // remove that `UIActivityIndicatorView`, if you showed one

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender:self];
    }];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController setKey:_key]
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can remove all of this, just perform the segue, but then have the destination view controller present itself, show the activity indicator view, perform the api calls, and remove the activity indicator view. This is a more dramatic refactoring of the code, but is probably a better UX.

But, bottom line, from within `prepareForSegue` you cannot do something asynchronous, and expect the destination view controller to wait for it, even if you employ the completion block pattern. You'd have to use the `IBAction` approach if you want to do all of this before performing the segue. Or, like I suggested here, just do all of this asynchronous request stuff in the destination view controller. For some reason, transitioning immediately to the destination view controller (and showing the `UIActivityIndicatorView` there) is more satisfying UX than delaying the presentation of the destination view controller (even though they're functionally very similar).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code to something like that:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

   [self doSomethingToGetKey:account completion:^{
      [segue.destinationViewController setKey:_key];
   }];

}

-(void)doSomethingToGetKey:(ACAccount *)account completion:(void (^)(void)completion{

[_apiObject postReverseOAuthTokenRequest:^(NSString *authenticationHeader) {

    APIObject *api = [APIObject APIOSWithAccount:account];
    [api verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {


        [api postReverseAuthAccessTokenWithAuthenticationHeader:authenticationHeader successBlock:^(NSString *oAuthToken, NSString *oAuthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {

            _key = oAuthToken;
            _secret = oAuthTokenSecret;
            _userId = userID;

            if (completion)
               completion();

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"ERROR 1, %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            exit(1);

        }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"ERROR 2: %@",error.description);
        exit(1);

    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"ERROR 3: %@",error.description);
    exit(1);

}];

};
```

Comment: You have to call completion block from `successBlock` of `postReverseAuthAccessTokenWithAuthenticationHeader` method