# segue programmatically not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a problem with a segue. I have "next" button:

```
- (IBAction)NextButton:(id)sender {
//...
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"adaugaScore" sender:self];
}
```

and this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"adaugaScore"])
    {
        ScoreViewController *scoreVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        scoreVC.score = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
    }
}
```

My app crashes at this line:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"adaugaScore" sender:self];
```

With this error:

```
has no segue with identifier 'adaugaScore''
```

Comment: Does your StoryBoard have a segue named `adaugaScore`?

Comment: Die you actually create a segue in your storyboard, connected it between the right viewControllers and gave it the exact same identifier?

Comment: No. i want perform programmatically this segue

Comment: The call (of the segue) can be done programmatically, but the segue has to exist on the Storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set storyboard id/name(adaugaScore) in your storyboard to your controller. Check : [What is a StoryBoard ID and how can i use this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this) for more information.

EDIT :
To use the segue name refer : [How do i set a modal segue (programmatically) to a push segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637945/how-do-i-set-a-modal-segue-programmatically-to-a-push-segue)

Comment: so in this case "adaugaScore" it's my identifier segue, or?

Answer (score 0):

Set the segue.identifier to be adaugaScore. This is done by clicking the segue and in the properties panel setting the identifier.